# Is $sin(x)$ a contraction on $[0,1]$?

Tags: contraction-operator

I see that the derivative of the function is $cos(x)$ and in $[0,1]$ this can take the value $cos(0)=1$ implying that is not a contraction. Is this correct ?

Comment: This is correct, and it is the "short version" of pre-kidney's answer. Note, indeed, that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is another way of writing the derivative of $\sin$ at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sin x$ was a contraction on $[0,1]$ then there would exist a constant $k\in [0,1)$ such that $|\sin x-\sin y|\leq k|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]$. To show that this is not the case, we just need a way of picking $x$ and $y$ to contradict the inequality. In fact we can choose $y=0$ and any $x$ sufficiently close to, but not equal to, $0$ such that $$\frac{\sin x}{x}>k.$$
And this, in turn, can always be done, since
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1,
$$
as is [famously known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Comment: so i just need to pick 2 numbers that dont respect this condition and it is done, thanks

Comment: yes, for every $k$ you would need to find $x,y$ that don't satisfy the condition.

Comment: I sometimes wonder why L'Hôpital's rule is used in cases where the limit is simply the *definition* of the derivative ...